# Implementation of deque

Tags: c++, c++11, queue

What can be simplified, altered, or implemented differently? I would like to know if there's a way to further improve this code.

```
#ifndef _DEQUE_H_
#define _DEQUE_H_
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
class Deque
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Type element = {};
        Node* prev = nullptr;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };
    size_t count;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
public:
    //Member functions
    Deque();
    Deque(const Deque & deq);
    Deque(Deque && deq);
    Deque & operator = (const Deque & deq);
    Deque & operator = (Deque && deq);
    ~Deque();

    //Element access
    //const Type & at(Deque pos) const; Not implemented
    //template <typename Type>
    //const Type & operator[](size_type pos) const; Not implemented
    const Type & front() const;
    const Type & back() const;

    //Iterators
    //TODO: Implement in the near future 

    //Capacity
    bool empty() const;
    size_t size() const;
    //size_t max_size() const noexcept; Not implemented

    //Modifiers
    void push_front(const Type & tp);
    void push_back(const Type & tp);

    //void emplace_front(); Not implemented
    //void emplace_back(); Not implemented

    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();

    void clear() noexcept;
    void swap(Deque & deq) noexcept;
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type>::Deque() : count(0), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
{
    //Body of the constructor class
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type>::Deque(const Deque & deq) : count(deq.count), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
{
    for (const Node* n_ptr = deq.head; n_ptr != nullptr; n_ptr = n_ptr->next)
    {
        Node* n_ptr_new = new Node;
        n_ptr_new->element = n_ptr->element;
        if (head == nullptr && tail == nullptr)
        {
            head = n_ptr_new;
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = n_ptr_new;
            n_ptr_new->prev = tail;
            n_ptr_new->next = nullptr;
            tail = n_ptr_new;
        }
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type>::Deque(Deque && deq) : count(deq.count), head(deq.head), tail(deq.tail)
{
    deq.count = 0;
    deq.head = nullptr;
    deq.tail = nullptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type> & Deque<Type>::operator = (const Deque & deq)
{
    if (this == &deq)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    Deque tmp(deq);
    std::swap(count, tmp.count);
    std::swap(head, tmp.head);
    std::swap(tail, tmp.tail);
    return *this;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type> & Deque<Type>::operator = (Deque && deq)
{
    if (this == &deq)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    std::swap(count, deq.count);
    std::swap(head, deq.head);
    std::swap(tail, deq.tail);
    return *this;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type>::~Deque()
{
    while (head)
    {
        Node* n_ptr_del = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete n_ptr_del;
    }
    count = 0;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::push_front(const Type & tp)
{
    Node* n_ptr_new = new Node;
    n_ptr_new->element = tp;
    if (head == nullptr && tail == nullptr)
    {
        head = n_ptr_new;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        n_ptr_new->next = head;
        n_ptr_new->prev = nullptr;
        head->prev = n_ptr_new;
        head = n_ptr_new;
    }
    ++count;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::push_back(const Type & tp)
{
    Node* n_ptr_new = new Node;
    n_ptr_new->element = tp;
    if (head == nullptr && tail == nullptr)
    {
        head = n_ptr_new;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = n_ptr_new;
        n_ptr_new->prev = tail;
        n_ptr_new->next = nullptr;
        tail = n_ptr_new;
    }
    ++count;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::pop_front()
{
    if (empty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Can't pop from empty list");
    }

    if (head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        --count;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    Node* n_ptr_del = head;
    head = head->next;
    head->prev = nullptr;
    --count;
    delete n_ptr_del;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::pop_back()
{
    if (empty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Can't pop from empty list");
    }

    if (head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        --count;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    Node* n_ptr_del = tail;
    tail = tail->prev;
    tail->next = nullptr;
    --count;
    delete n_ptr_del;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
bool Deque<Type>::empty() const
{
    return head == nullptr;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
const Type & Deque<Type>::front() const
{
    if (empty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("List<Type>::top: empty stack");
    }
    return head->element;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
const Type & Deque<Type>::back() const
{
    if (empty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("List<Type>::top: empty stack");
    }
    return tail->element;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
size_t Deque<Type>::size() const
{
    return count;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::clear() noexcept
{
    while (count)
    {
        pop_back();
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::swap(Deque & deq) noexcept
{
    Deque temp(deq);
    deq = std::move(*this);
    *this = std::move(temp);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif // _DEQUE_H_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use appropriate `#include`s

The code refers to a number of things, such as `std::size_t` and `std::swap` which do not have the corresponding `#include`s.  The code should have the following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>
```

### Don't define the default constructor

The default constructor for the `Deque` does nothing except for initializing members.  Instead, you should use in-class member initializers and let the constructor be generated by the compiler as you have with `Node`.  See [CppCoreGuidelines C.45](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-default).

### Don't use leading underscores in names

Anything with a leading underscore is a *reserved name* in C++ (and in C).  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for details.  In this case it applies to your chosen name for the include guard.

### Simplify your code

The code for `push_back` and `push_front` and a number of other functions can be simplified considerably. In the case of `push_back`, for example, by using the autogenerated constructor for `Node`:

```
template <typename Type>
void Deque<Type>::push_back(const Type & tp)
{
    if (tail) {
        tail = tail->next = new Node{tp, tail, nullptr};
    } else {
        head = tail = new Node{tp, nullptr, nullptr};
    }
    ++count;
}
```

### Fix the error messages

Some of the error messages don't seem to match what they're signalling very well.  For example, if we attempt to use `back()` on an empty `Deque`, it says

```
throw std::out_of_range("List<Type>::top: empty stack");
```

This would be a very confusing and unhelpful error message!

### Use your own functions

In some cases, the code uses `count` to determine when the deque is empty, in others it checks if `head == nullptr` and still others it uses `empty()`.  I'd recommend choosing one mechanism and using it exclusively.  Likewise, if you use your own functions, the `copy` could be as simple as this:

```
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type>::Deque(const Deque & deq) {
    for (auto curr = deq.head; curr; curr = curr->next) {
        push_back(curr->element);
    }
}
```

### Consider supporting list initialization

At the moment, a construction like this is not supported:

```
Deque<std::string> d3{"alpha", "beta", "gamma"};
```

It's easy to do, however.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
template <typename Type>
Deque<Type>::Deque(std::initializer_list<Type> list) {
    for (auto& item : list) {
        push_back(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- > `Node` wants a constructor

  ```
  Node(const Type& tp, Node * prev = nullptr, Node * next = nullptr)
     : element(tp)
     , prev(prev)
     , next(next)
  {}
  ```
- > What can be simplified

  `push`s and `pop`s. There is common functionality between a special and common cases. Consider for example `push_front`: after the push a new node would become `head`, no matter what:

  ```
  push_front(const Type& tp) {
      node = new Node(tp, nullptr, head);
      if (head == 0) {
          tail = node;
      } else {
          head->prev = node;
      }
      head = node;
  }
  ```

  Other three function can be similarly streamlined.
- A copy constructor shares too much code with `push_back`. Consider consolidating the common base. Ditto for a destructor and `clear`.
- You may want to assert your invariants: if you have, say, `head == nullptr`, you must also have `tail == nullptr` and `count == 0`.